# AutoCompleteTextView with custom ArrayAdapter and Filter

Tags: android, filter, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I have a problem when I'm trying to Filter results in AutoCompleteTextView from LogCat I know that filtering is performed correct but it's not refreshing the view :/ Did I forget about something any suggestions or help?

Here is source code of filter.

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter myFilter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Perform filtering with constraint: " + constraint.toString());
            List<String> resultsSuggestions = new ArrayList<String>();
            Log.i(TAG, "COUNT: " + getCount());
            for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {
                if(getItem(i).getSuggestionValue().startsWith(constraint.toString())){
                    Log.i(TAG, "ADDED");
                    resultsSuggestions.add(getItem(i).getSuggestionValue());
                }
            }
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = resultsSuggestions;
            results.count = resultsSuggestions.size();
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
    return myFilter;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The missing part is that I need to set the new values from filter so I just simply changed the

```
publushResults();
```

and now it's working. The correct code bellow.

```
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        clear();
        ArrayList<Suggestions> newValues = (ArrayList<Suggestions>) results.values;
        for (int i = 0; i < newValues.size(); i++) {
            add(newValues.get(i));
        }
        if(results.count>0){
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else{
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Update - On inputting and removing all the characters in search textbox very quickly crashes the application on newValues.size() or newValues.get(i) as newValues might be null. So, here's the code you should use:

```
@Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        clear();
        ArrayList<Suggestions> newValues = (ArrayList<Suggestions>) results.values;
        if(newValues !=null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < newValues.size(); i++) {
                add(newValues.get(i));
            }
            if(results.count>0){
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else{
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Robert, Yours is not copied, his is.